# How do I include italic text in geom_text_repel or geom_text labels for ggplot?

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, plotmath, ggrepel

Is it possible to pass partially italicized text labels into ggplot? I have tried using the `expression` and `italic` commands (`expression(paste(italic("some text")))`), but these cannot be passed into a data frame because the result of the commands is not atomic. Setting the parameter `fontface = "italic"` also doesn't suffice, since this italicizes the entire label, rather than just a select set of characters in the label. For instance, I would like some necessarily italicized Latin phrases  to be italicized in a label (such as "in vivo" in "in vivo point").

```
library(ggplot)
library(ggrepel)

df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,2), V2 = c(2,4), V3 = c("in vivo point","another point"))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) + geom_point() + geom_text_repel(aes(label = V3))
```

Comment: Is adding `fontface = "italic"` not an option:  `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) + geom_point() + geom_text_repel(aes(label = V3), fontface = "italic")` ?

Comment: To be somewhat fair to the OP, the help on those `_repel` functions fail to include all supported aesthetics directly in the text but it _does_ say _"See the documentation for those functions [geom_text/geom_label] for more details"_

Comment: Sorry, in a rush, I forgot to include that only a substring of the label is to be italicized; I will amend the question.

Comment: If you use `parse = TRUE` you can use `?plotmath`, though you'll have to reconfigure your labels.

Comment: Thank you! As an aside, this actually appears not to work in the current stable version of ggrepel, but the development version supports plotmath expressions. (https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/60). If you would like, you can post as an answer so I can mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `parse = TRUE` to pass `?plotmath` expressions (as strings) to `geom_text` or `geom_text_repel`. You'll have to rewrite the strings as plotmath, but if it's not too many it's not too bad.

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,2), V2 = c(2,4), 
                 V3 = c("italic('in vivo')~point", "another~point"))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = V1, y = V2, label = V3)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_text_repel(parse = TRUE)
```

[image: plot with partial italic label]

Comment: `element_text()` has an argument called `face`. I am not sure why `geom_text()` doesn't have this option.

Comment: FYI, to see possible rendering options: `demo(plotmath)`

Comment: geom_text() calls the option fontface -- http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Fonts/

Comment: @hd1 From the question: "Setting the parameter `fontface = "italic"` also doesn't suffice, since this italicizes the entire label, rather than just a select set of characters in the label."