# Using plotmath with geom_label_repel to have subscripts within the labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, ggrepel, plotmath

I am trying to have subscripts in my `geom_label`. e.g.

Maine 
A<sub>po</sub> (km/h) = 9 
Q<sub>t</sub> (m/s) = 90

I am aware of using `[x]` to get subscripts but I am not sure how to achieve that when I want to get the label values (partly) from a column. I tried using tidyeval (`!!`) to no avail. Even simply changing `parse = T` gives me errors. It could be something rudimentary that I am overlooking, but after reading this thread [using plotmath in ggrepel labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845001/using-plotmath-in-ggrepel-labels), I am not sure if it is as simple as I thought.

Here is with what I have so far. I provided the packages and the data I have used, along with data cleaning/preparation steps. Finally, I've shown the code that I have used for creating the "preliminary" plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(usmap)
library(ggrepel)
library(rlang)
```

```
read.table(text = "State     Apo    Qt
NJ  1     10
MO  2     20
SD  3     30
NY  4     40
FL  5     50
OK  6     60
NE  7     70
KY  8     80
ME  9     90
CA  10  100
NC  11  110
MA  12  120
CT  13  140", header = T, stringsAsFactor = F) -> ex1
```

```
# get the states full names
region <- state.name[match(ex1$State,state.abb)]
region <- str_to_title(region)

# US map data (50 States)
us1 <- usmap::us_map()

# adding full names to the dataset
ex_df <- cbind(region = region, ex1)

# adding dataset values to the map data (only states with data)
us_val1 <- left_join(ex_df, us1, by = c("region" = "full")) 

# full map dataset joined by ex1 dataset to draw the map
us_map1 <- left_join(us1, ex_df, by = c("full" ="region")) %>% 
           mutate(qQt = replace_na(Qt, 0))

# creating a dataset with centroids of the states (only the ones in ex1)
us_centroids1 <- 
  us_val1 %>%
  group_by(region) %>% 
  summarise(centroid.x = mean(range(x)), 
            centroid.y = mean(range(y)),
            label = unique(State),
            `Apo` = unique(Apo),
            `Qt` = unique(Qt))
```

```
## drawing the plot
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = us_map1, 
               aes(x,y, group = group, fill = Qt), 
               color = "black",
               size = .1) +
  geom_label_repel(data = us_centroids1, 
                   aes(centroid.x, centroid.y, 
                       label = paste(region, "\n Apo (km/h) = ", `Apo`,  "\n Qt (m/s) =", `Qt`)),
                   size = 5/14*8,
                   box.padding = 1,
                   parse = F) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(name = expression(Q[t]~(m/s)),
                       breaks = c(0, seq(10,130,20)),
                       labels = c("", seq(10,130,20)),
                       limits = c(0, 130),
                       colors = c("#DCDCDC", "lightblue", "green"),
                       guide = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 0.8, barheight = 18)) +
  
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Your working minimal working example is not-so-minimal, so it's somewhat involved to see what's going on. Can't you just pre-compute the label values like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72961962/r-programmatically-changing-ggplot-scale-labels-to-greek-letters-with-expressio

Comment: @socialscientist it's fairly minimal, I guess I can take out the `scale_fill_...`  out or just use random x and y datapoints instead of creating a map but that would just make the plot look crude. Considering the comments I provided, I don't see it very complicated. About your suggestion, I have tried that route before. If I mutate a new column and try `parse = T` I get the following error ```Error in parse(text = text[[i]]) : <text>:1:5: unexpected symbol         1: New Jersey         ^``` and I cannot use `label_parse` since these are not axis labels.

Comment: Please add the example of the above. label_parse works for non-axis labels as well.

Comment: @socialscientist adding every variation that I've tried would clutter the question, if you can post a working solution with label_parse, that'd be appreciated. Although I cannot see how's that possible and doubt that you're onto something. Read the answer below to see why it's more complicated than just creating the labels beforehand. Cheers.

Comment: It would be possible to construct this plotmath expression as a string. You could use string interpolation with glue, which would remove the need to use `pmap()`, but then you would have to parse it. I neither approach is substantially less complex than the other

Comment: The biggest downside of putting code in a string though, is that you loose the benefits of syntax highlighting, which is why I don't like it and did not use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a pain, since plotmath doesn't appear to have line breaks. Thus, you have to work around it with `atop()`. Use `bquote()` to insert variable values into the expression. This only works on one element at once, thus we have to `pmap()` over the three variables.

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = us_map1, 
               aes(x,y, group = group, fill = Qt), 
               color = "black",
               size = .1) +
  geom_label_repel(data = us_centroids1, 
                   aes(centroid.x, centroid.y, 
                       label = pmap(list(region, Apo, Qt), 
                                    \(x,y,z) bquote(atop(.(x), # first line of lab
                                                         atop(A[po] (km/h) == .(y), # second line
                                                              Q[t] (m/s) == .(z)) # third line
                                                         )
                                                    )
                                    )
                       ),
                   size = 5/14*8,
                   box.padding = 1,
                   parse = T) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(name = expression(Q[t]~(m/s)),
                       breaks = c(0, seq(10,130,20)),
                       labels = c("", seq(10,130,20)),
                       limits = c(0, 130),
                       colors = c("#DCDCDC", "lightblue", "green"),
                       guide = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 0.8, barheight = 18)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>