# How to apply APA's rules to p-values inside geom_bracket()

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, p-value, t-test

this is a [follow up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76280451/how-to-italicize-t-and-p-values-using-stat-pvalue-manual-in-ggplot2) question. How can I apply APA's rule dynamically in `geom_bracket()` ?

- RULES:

"A p-value larger than .01 should be reported to two decimal places, p-values between .01 and .001 to three decimal places, and p-values less than .001 simply as p < .001." [(source)](https://www.statology.org/how-to-report-p-value/)

- Code:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(rstatix)   # Identify outliers and Stats Summary function
library(ggpubr)    # Plot correlation
library(RVAideMemoire) # Shapiro test on groups 
library(glue) # Round p value in the plots 
library(stringr)
library(weights) ## remove 0.

### long:
  dfPaired <- df
  dfLong <- df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = TEST, values_from = VALUE)

### Create list outside of the loop
    
    PairedtestResults <- list()
    
    ### run loop

    for (bb in seq(from = 1, to = 4, by = 2)) {
      
      
      ## Create vars
      
      PairedVar1 <- dfPaired[bb+1]     #G1 Variables
      PairednVar1 <- names(PairedVar1)
      dfPaired$PairedVar1Unlist <- unlist(PairedVar1)
      
      PairedVar2 <- dfPaired[bb+2]     #G2 Variables
      PairednVar2 <- names(PairedVar2)
      dfPaired$PairedVar2Unlist <- unlist(PairedVar2)
      
      ### store and perform tests:
      
      PairedtestResults[[bb]] <-  t.test(dfPairedFiltered$PairedVar1Unlist, dfPairedFiltered$PairedVar2Unlist,
                                         paired = T, data =  dfPaired, exact = F)
      
      PairedtestResults[[bb]]$data.name <- str_glue("{PairednVar1} and {PairednVar2}")


## wide to long to plot it:


### wide to long to plot data and extract eff size:
  
  dfplot <- dfPairedFiltered %>% 
    dplyr::select(ID, PairedVar1Unlist, PairedVar2Unlist) %>%  
    pivot_longer(c(PairedVar1Unlist, PairedVar2Unlist),
                 names_to = "TEST",
                 values_to = "VALUE") %>% 
    mutate(LANGUAGE = case_when(TEST == "PairedVar1Unlist" ~ "GROUP1",
                                TEST == "PairedVar2Unlist" ~  "GROUP2")) %>% 
    mutate(TEST = as.factor(TEST),
           TEST = fct_relevel(TEST, c("GROUP1", "GROUP2"))) %>% 
    dplyr::select(ID, VALUE, TEST)
      
    }

  dfLong %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x = TEST, y = VALUE)) +
    stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar",
                 width = 0.15) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = TEST), outlier.colour = "yellow", outlier.shape = 18,
                 outlier.size= 2, notch = F) +
        geom_bracket(xmin = "TEST1", xmax = "TEST2",
                     y.position = 250,
                     position = "identity",
                    label =  glue::glue(
                       paste0(
                         "~italic(t) ({PairedtestResults[[bb]][['parameter']]}) == {round(PairedtestResults[[bb]][['statistic']], 2)}*','",
                         "~italic(p) == '{rd(PairedtestResults[[bb]][['p.value']], digits = 3)}'*','"
                       )
                     ),
                     type = "expression",
                     inherit.aes = F,
                    data = dfLong)
```

**How can I dynamically apply APA's rule to `geom_bracket()`'s `label` ?**

- edit:
  I tried to make a custom function to change the p-value before passing it into the graph, but it isn't working:

```
convertToAPA <- function(x) { 
   
    if (x < 0.001) {
     
     PairedtestResults[[bb]][['p.value']] <- as.numeric(.001)
     
   } else if (x >= 0.001 && x <= 0.01) {
     
     PairedtestResults[[bb]][['p.value']] <- as.numeric(rd(x, digits = 3))
     
   } else if (x > .01) {
     
     PairedtestResults[[bb]][['p.value']] <- as.numeric(rd(x, digits = 2))
     
   }
   
   return(PairedtestResults[[bb]][['p.value']])
 }
```

- data:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:31, TEST1 = c(70, 66, 59, 61, 73, 90, 59, 
82, 60, 40, 77, 49, 61, 92, 56, 56, 68, 87, 87, 87, 79, 45, 83, 
50, 44, 95, 82, 134, 42, 70, 84), TEST2 = c(73, 140, 59, 70, 
107, 91, 95, 133, 80, 45, 96, 50, 56, 120, 110, 110, 83, 113, 
114, 134, 57, 65, 71, 52, 56, 138, 126, 118, 72, 87, 112), TEST3 = c(34, 
51, 67, 33, 56, 37, 38, 46, 47, 45, 45, 95, 39, 47, 32, 42, 36, 
45, 39, 48, 35, 38, 60, 72, 31, 49, 60, 30, 27, 56, 38), TEST4 = c(40, 
45, 46, 30, 72, 26, 22, 26, 27, 38, 21, 65, 19, 25, 32, 66, 50, 
29, 16, 35, 40, 34, 40, 54, 28, 43, 48, 32, 36, 52, 23)), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you make a MINIMAL reproducible example please?!

Comment: I'm sorry, isn't this minimal? I really didn't understand. I posted the loop because that's how I'm storing the tests in a list (PairedtestResults[[bb]][['p.value']]), hence a single test result may not work the same way as storing the results in a list, which is what I need

Comment: Hi Larissa. Could you please update your question to make it reproducible? As is your code is not working. Does you example data refer to `df` or `dfLong`? Probably the latter. Also, `dfPairedFiltered` is used but not defined in your code. Overall your approach looks quite complicated. But without a working example it#s hard to figure out how your code could be fixed.